# Keep receiving 404 Nginx when deploying rails app on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, nginx, digital-ocean

I am following this tutorial with my own rails project: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-passenger-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

And I keep arriving at a 404 Nginx not found error. Printing out the log I recieved this

```
error: 2014/11/16 14:08:13 [error] 20149#0: *29 "/home/rails/whattodo/public/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 70.52.174.228, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "104.131.76.121"
2014/11/16 14:08:14 [error] 20149#0: *29 open() "/home/rails/whattodo/public/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 70.52.174.228, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "104.131.76.121".
```

Here is my nginx file:

```
server {
listen 80 defaultserver;
passengerenabled on;
passengerappenv development;
root /whattodo/public;
}
```

I added this index file to the public folder file, even though I didn't think it would be necessary, and still the error remains. Any help or directions you think I should be heading to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you check the server and make sure that `/home/rails/whattodo/public/index.html` actually exists?

Comment: Hey @Alec-Sanger, my apologies. It is meant to be /whattodo/public. I made the change in the appropriate file, but still no luck! Is there a certain form that the root should be taking? THe /whattodo/public/index.html file exists!

Comment: Very strange. After you made the change to nginx, did you restart the nginx service?

Comment: Yeah via ' sudo nginx -s reload'

Comment: As far as I remember it it should be `passenger_enabled` and `passenger_app_env`so you appear to be missing some underscores